# sequential countdowntimer with handler wont update textView correctly

Tags: java, android, multithreading, countdowntimer, android-handler

I was trying to build some sort of sequential countdown. Meaning, that I build up a queue of "exercises", each one containing a specific duration, which is the countdown time. In a custom Countdown class, I pop these exercises off the queue and use the duration as countdown. 
I want these countdowns to run one after another. For this I built a Countdown class, based on the code basis of the abstract class `CountDownTimer`.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ExerciseMeCountDownTimer {

    private static final int MSG_COUNTDOWN = 100;
    private static final int MSG_FINISH = 99;
    private ArrayDeque<Exercise> eq;
    private long mMillisInFuture;
    private int mCountdownInterval;
    private String name;
    private long mStopTimeInFuture;
    CountdownHandler cHandler;

    public ExerciseMeCountDownTimer(ArrayList<Exercise> elist,
            Button startStopButton, TextView countdownText,
            CountdownHandler cHandler) {

        this.cHandler = cHandler;
        eq = new ArrayDeque<Exercise>(elist);
        this.start();
    }

    public final void cancel() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    private synchronized final ExerciseMeCountDownTimer start() {
        if (!eq.isEmpty()) {
            Exercise e = eq.pop();
            this.mMillisInFuture = Long.parseLong(e.getDuration());
            this.mCountdownInterval = 30;
            this.name = e.getName();
        } else {
            onFinish();
            return this;
        }

        if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
            onFinish();
            return this;
        }
        mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
        return this;
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Message msg = cHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_COUNTDOWN);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        String text = String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%02d:%02d:%03d",
                millisUntilFinished / 100000, millisUntilFinished / 1000,
                millisUntilFinished % 1000);
        data.putString("countdown", text);
        msg.setData(data);
        cHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        if (!eq.isEmpty()) {
            this.start();
        }

        Message msg = cHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_FINISH);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        String text = String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "00:00:000");
        data.putString("finish", text);
        msg.setData(data);
        cHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private static final int MSG = 1;

    // handles counting down
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            final long millisLeft = mStopTimeInFuture
                    - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                onFinish();
            } else if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                // no tick, just delay until done
                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft);
            } else {
                long lastTickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                onTick(millisLeft);

                // take into account user's onTick taking time to
                // execute
                long delay = lastTickStart + mCountdownInterval
                        - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                // special case: user's onTick took more than interval
                // to
                // complete, skip to next interval
                while (delay < 0)
                    delay += mCountdownInterval;

                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay);
            }
        }

    };

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

The important part is the `sendMessage` part, where I send the time left on the countdown to a `handler` of my `MainActivity`, which then, should update a textview.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

class CountdownHandler extends Handler {
private static final int MSG_COUNTDOWN = 100;
private static final int MSG_FINISH = 99;
private MainActivity mActivity;

CountdownHandler(MainActivity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == MSG_COUNTDOWN) {
        String text = msg.getData().getString("countdown");
        this.mActivity.sayLog(text);
    }
    if (msg.what == MSG_FINISH) {
        String text = msg.getData().getString("finish");
        this.mActivity.sayLog(text);
    }

}
```

And finally updates the `textView` in `MainActivty`

```
public void sayLog(String text) {
    countdown.setText(text);
}
```

ExerciseMeCountDownTimer is called by

```
new ExerciseMeCountDownTimer(elist, cHandler);
```

on some onClick().

The problem is, that sometimes (actually most of the time) the textView is not updated properly. It stops updating on random times like 00:05:211 etc. 
Would anyone mind telling me why this is keeps happening? Maybe also adding a solution or at least some literature (maybe pointing out some sections) which I should read to understand the problem? I am also upen for alternative approaches, as I am new to this "handler", "threads" thing in android.

**EDIT**

- the textview was updating, but the textview was clickable. Whenever I clicked on the textview it stopped updating!
- as the accepted answer shows, I decided to use the direkt approach of updating the appropriate textview inside the `onTick()` method.

Comment: You know that `onTick()` runs on the `UI` thread, right? Is there a reason you can't update it there without the `Handler`

Comment: yeah I know that. I already tried updating the textview there, but android didnt really like that, complaining about the view hierarchy can only get modified by the activity that created the textview. But I changed alot since then, let me try it again.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `ExerciseMeCountDownTimer ` from the main thread

Comment: okay, you where right, I can actually use the `onTick()`... strange this didnt work before. I am passing the textView to `ExerciseMeCountDownTimer(elist, countdownTextview, cHandler)` The problem, that the textView freezes is still there. It happens, when I click (mouse, in the emulator) on the textview...

Comment: I was going to suggest `onFinish()` but you were using `onTick()` above. Anyway, why are you clicking the textview?

Comment: I am clicking it, because a use could potentially click it.

Comment: Well, I understand that but why would you want it to be clickable if it is being updated by something else. Make it not clickable

Comment: Oh jeez, good point! Thanks... ahh great working! If you want, add your first comment as answer and I will mark it as accepted!

Comment: Done. I gave an example of how it *could* be done. But feel free to edit with your working solution if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Handler` and things in this situation is making it overly complicated.

`CountDownTimer`s `onTick()` and `onFinish()` both run on the `UI Thread` so updating `TextViews` and other `View`s from either method can be done easily just by passing a reference of the `View` to the constructor of the class, as you are already doing. Then you simply update it in the method needed.

```
// could create a member variable for the TextView with your other member variables
...
mTV;
```

then in your constructor assign it
    // removed reference to Handler--you already have reference to TextView here
    public ExerciseMeCountDownTimer(ArrayList elist,
            Button startStopButton, TextView countdownText) {
         mTV = countdownText;

then update in whichever method is needed

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    String text = String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%02d:%02d:%03d",
            millisUntilFinished / 100000, millisUntilFinished / 1000,
            millisUntilFinished % 1000);
    mTV.setText(text);  // set the text here


}

public void onFinish() {
    if (!eq.isEmpty()) {
        this.start();
    }
```